# Passing key/value objects as a parameter in a Javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, object, parameters, constructor

I'm setting up an object constructor and would like to pass an key/value object as a parameter. I was wondering what would be the correct way to do so? Right now I'm just passing the keys as the parameters:

```
(function() {
    function Venue(name, poor, satisfactory, excellent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.serviceRatings = {
            poor: poor,
            satisfactory: satisfactory,
            excellent: excellent
        };
    }

  var dining = new Venue("dining", .1, .15, .2);

  console.log(dining["serviceRatings"]["satisfactory"] // .15
}());
```

Although this works, coming from a Ruby background it only felt right to pass the object itself and assign the it's values in the initializer. This was the best equivalent I could think of:

```
class Venue
  def initialize(name, serviceRatings = {})
    @name = name
    @poor = serviceRatings[:poor]
    @satisfactory = serviceRatings[:satisfactory]
    @excellent = serviceRatings[:excellent]
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do this in Javascript? The way I have things written now makes me feel as if I'm bloating my constructer's list of parameters (unless this **is** the right way to do this).

Comment: Can pass in one object argument instead of multiple primitives if that is what you are asking. Not really clear what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an object just like you did in your ruby class.

```
function Venue(name, options) {
    this.name = name;
    this.serviceRatings = options;
}

var dining = new Venue("dining",{
        poor: .1,
        satisfactory: .15,
        excellent: .2
    });
```

Above will create the same output as before. It's worth to mention that ecmascript 2015 brought classes to javascript - so you could also write it like this:

```
class Venue {
    constructor(name, options = {}) {
        this.name = name;
        this.serviceRatings = options;
    }
}
```

Above we're using an empty object as `default parameter`, which is also an es2015 feature.

If you want to have default key names, something like this will make it

```
class Venue {
    constructor(name, options = {}) {
        this.name = name;
        this.serviceRatings = Object.assign({
           poor: undefined,
           satisfactory: undefined,
           excellent: undefined
        }, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: For either example, is there a way to write default key names within the `options` object? Just curious.

Comment: Yes, edited my answer @CarlEdwards - this will work in both examples - but be aware that Object.assign hasn't best browser support, so you might need to polyfill it depending on the environment you're running this in

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping more browsers support the second method soon. Much more convenient.

Comment: Yes, I feel the same.. @CarlEdwards

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
(function() {
        function Venue(name, serviceRatings) {
            this.name = name;
            this.serviceRatings = serviceRatings;
        }

        var dining = new Venue("dining", {
            poor:.1,
            satisfactory:.15,
            excellent:.2
        });

        console.log(dining["serviceRatings"]["satisfactory"]) // .15
    }());
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it is possible to pass an object as an argument.

```
// naive ES5 version
function Venue(name, serviceRatings) {
    this.name = name;
    this.serviceRatings = serviceRatings;
}
```

The problem with this naive approach is that Objects in JavaScript are mutable. If you assign the Object like above, your object state can be mutated accidentally. For example:

```
var ratings = { poor: 0, satisfactory: 2, excellent: 8 };
var diner = new Venue('diner', ratings);

ratings.poor = 12;
var burgerJoint = new Venue('my burgers', ratings);
```

Here you mutate ratings after diner was created, and you accidentally set diner.serviceRatings.poor to 12.

You can protect your code from this by copying the values of your object:

```
// improved with Object.assign
function Venue(name, serviceRatings) {
    this.name = name;
    this.serviceRatings = Object.assign({}, serviceRatings);
}
```

Object.assign() copies every property from seviceRatings to {}; this way later modifications to the other object do not affect your member property.

If you are using ES2015, you can use object destructuring, which has additional benefits: it makes your expected data structure explicit; and allows you to specify default values:

```
// ES2015 version with explicit parameters and default values
function Venue(name, { poor = 0, satisfactory = 0, excellent = 0 }) {
    this.name = name;
    this.serviceRatings = { poor, satisfactory, excellent };
}
```

Edit: as seen in another answer, if you are using ES2015, you might as well as use the class syntactic sugar:

```
// ES2015 version using class definition
class Venue
    constructor (name, { poor = 0, satisfactory = 0, excellent = 0 }) {
        this.name = name;
        this.serviceRatings = { poor, satisfactory, excellent };
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

arguments will contain all the parameters passed to the function as a list.

```
(function() {
    function Venue() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }

    var dining = new Venue("dining", .1, .15, .2);

}());
```